# Making a list deconstruct like a tuple, or make a tuple iterate like a list, in scala

Tags: scala

I've got some variables, and I want to create new variables by running each of them through a function.  So essentially I've currently got

```
val formatted1 = format(raw1)
val formatted2 = format(raw2)
val formatted3 = format(raw3)
```

Is there any way to do this all in one line?  Looking for something like

```
val (formatted1, formatted2, formatted3) = (raw1, raw2, raw3).map(format)
```

but that seems to combine features of a List and features of a Tuple in incompatible ways.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can map over tuple, but if you put your items in List:

```
val List(formatted1, formatted2, formatted3) = List(raw1, raw2, raw3).map(format)
```

This works with many other collections, like Seq, Array and so on (types on both sides has to be the same! but you can have more general type on the left: e.g. `val Seq(...) = List(...)`).

For Lists (but not for other types) you can also write something like this:

```
val formatted1::formatted2::formatted3::Nil = List(raw1, raw2, raw3).map(format)
```

Starting from Scala 2.10 you can perform same trick with Seq:

```
val formatted +: formatted2 +: formatted3 +: _ = ....
```

Comment: Is there a performance difference depending on whether you go Seq or List or Array on lhs and/or rhs?  Compilation speed difference?

Comment: Such things done via [extractors](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/extractors.html) and in particular via `unapplySeq` so I guess there will be some **really tiny** impact for Arrays (to wrap them in IndexedSeq).

Comment: @DaxFohl Actually, extractors are used for most things, but not for `List` -- these go through a shortcut instead of `unapplySeq`. Extracting to a `List` will most likely be a bit faster -- `javap` is your friend here, experiment with it!